# Can't get method notifydatasetchanged

Tags: java, android, arrays

the context : i have 2 class, a class Listactivity  and another class AudioListActivity in wich i have define a custom arrayadapter.
So in the ListActivity with oncreate, i call once my custom arrayadapter with 
setListAdapter (  MyListAdapter = new .... ) to populate my listview with 10 items. It works well.
My problem is that on an onclick, in listactivity : 1/ i call a thread to reload an array with 10 others items ( works well ) 2/ i want to refresh my listview with this array ( without setListAdapter again because i don t want to create another adapter object in memory ).
So i have think to notifydatasetchanged().
But when i try MyListAdapter. "completion" it doesn't give notifydatasetchanged.
Then how can i do ? how can i notify my arrayadapter to refresh the listview ?
need some help ! thank you !

heres Listactivity

```
 ListView ClassListView;

ListAdapter MyListAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

    ClassListView = getListView();
    ClassListView.addFooterView(footer);


    //chargement des données de la premiere page de la listview via LA thread
    threadChargeListe(0, "PremierePage", "aucun");


    setListAdapter(MyListAdapter=new AudioListAdapter(this, 0, MyApplication.getMyArrayDonneesListeAudio()));


    //Mise en place des listeners
    addListener();
}
private void addListener() {

    //listener bouton page suivante
    ImageButton MyPageSuivante = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pagesuivante);
    MyPageSuivante.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //chargement des données de la page suivante via LA thread
            int I = MyApplication.getMyArrayDonneesListeAudio().size();
            int idref = MyApplication.getMyArrayDonneesListeAudio().get(I - 1).getIdDemandeAudio();           /* calcul de la ref de l'audio pivot */
            chargeListe(idref, "PageSuivante", "aucun");                                                    
            MyListAdapter.  >>>>> HERE i CAN T ACCESS notifydatasetchanged ???
        }
    });
```

here are first lines of my arraydapter

```
public class AudioListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DonneesListeAudio> {


// Variables
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<DonneesListeAudio> DataOfListView;
private static LayoutInflater Inflater = null;
int classPosition = 0;
ViewWrapper Holder;
private long classTimeHeureLecture = 0;
private AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> MyAsynchTask;
private AtomicBoolean isThreadRunnning = new AtomicBoolean();
private AtomicBoolean isThreadPausing = new AtomicBoolean();

String classAudioFileName;


//Constructeur
public AudioListAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DonneesListeAudio> _Liste) {
    super(activity, textViewResourceId, _Liste);
    try {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.DataOfListView = _Liste;

        Inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}




//construction de la vue de l'item
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    classPosition = position;
    View ItemView = convertView;

    try {
        if (convertView == null) {  AND SO ON .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListAdapter` has no member `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You have to cast your `MyListAdapter` to `ArrayAdapter`, to access it.

```
((ArrayAdapter<DonneesListeAudio>) MyListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

check for typo

Comment: That's it ! you're right blackbelt ! i made a mistake when i wrote ListAdapter MyListAdapter. I should have write ArrayAdapter<DonneesListeAudio> MyArrayAdapter and then MyArrayDapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). You've saved me ! thank you again