# notifyDataSetChanged() does not seem to be working?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

This is my first time posting so please forgive me if i am not specific enough so... here is my delima..

I am trying to simply add a list dynamically when a button is clicked.

However after doing countless research, the solution that I have come up with does not seem to be working for me.

As I have mentioned in the above title, the method notifyDataSetChanged() is giving me the error 'cannot resolve method'. Any help would be appreciated, here is what I have.

```
public class ExercisesSection extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText userWorkoutInput;
    private Button addNewWorkoutButton;
    private ListAdapter edsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercises_section);

        initViews();
        handleIntentData();
        inputTextHandler();

    }
    //This method initializes all the views
    public void initViews(){
        userWorkoutInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userWorkoutInput);
        addNewWorkoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewWorkoutButton);
    }

    //This method makes the "Add new workout Button" clickable or not depending on user input
    public void inputTextHandler(){

        //userWorkoutInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userWorkoutInput);
        //addNewWorkoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewWorkoutButton);

        userWorkoutInput.addTextChangedListener(
                new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        boolean isEmpty = false;
                        if ((userWorkoutInput.getText().toString().trim()).equals("")) {
                            isEmpty = true;
                        }
                        addNewWorkoutButton.setEnabled(!isEmpty);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //An onClick method that will add user input into the list
    public void addWorkoutButtonClicked(View view){
        String input = (userWorkoutInput.getText().toString().trim());
        if (!input.equals("")){
            addItemToList(input);
            userWorkoutInput.setText("");   //Empties the edit text section
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void addItemToList(String input){

        String [] exercises = {input};
        edsAdapter = new CustomExerciseAdapter(this, exercises);

        ListView exerciseListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseListView);
        exerciseListView.setAdapter(edsAdapter);
        edsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this line is red! ERROR 'cannot resolve method'

        exerciseListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String exercise = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        //DO SOMETHING WHEN EXERCISE IS CLICKED
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    public void handleIntentData(){

        Bundle workoutData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (workoutData == null){
            return;
        }

        String workoutClicked = workoutData.getString("exerciseChosen");
        TextView exerciseChosenText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseChosenText);
        exerciseChosenText.setText(workoutClicked);
        exerciseChosenText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }


public class CustomExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public CustomExerciseAdapter(Context context, String[] workouts) {
        super(context, R.layout.exercise_custom_row ,workouts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_custom_row, parent, false);

        String singleExerciseItem = getItem(position);
        TextView exerciseTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseTV);
        exerciseTV.setText(singleExerciseItem);

        return customView;
    }
```

Comment: #1 Your `edsAdapter` has data type `ListAdapter` and initiated with `CustomExerciseAdapter`. Try changing `ListAdapter` to `CustomExerciseAdapter` as well and tell if issue resolved or not. #2 For doing some self debug of error try implementing `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in your adapter by Alt + Insert > Override Methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888673/cant-get-method-notifydatasetchanged/19888711#19888711

Comment: Thank you so much! It absolutely works!